# How to get a single digit from the sum of a number which is actually date format (15-06-2015)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know how can I get a single digit from the sum of a number which is actually date format (15-06-2015).

I want to convert this date format 15-06-2015 into a single digit by sum of that numbers.

for example: 15-05-2015 the output will be 1+5+0+5+2+0+1+5=(19)1+9=(10)1+0=1 final output

Also How can I get only date (15) from full date 15-05-2015

Comment: For date formatting in javaScript I suggest you use Moment.js. Here's the link http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Actually, I get date from another 3rd party services. but I need to get sum of all digits to form a single digit and also get only day from that date format

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function for the sum:

```
const sum = s => (s = ("" + s).match(/\d/g).reduce((a, v) => +v + a, 0)) > 9 ? sum(s) : s
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you would want to get all those numbers individually by invoking the methods on the date object that return each value.

For instance

```
var date = new Date(); 
console.log(date.getDate());
```

Would return 22 for me today on the 22nd of July. Check out [the Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) :)
You should be able to put together a function that will do what you need with the information on this page. Unless I misunderstood your needs there.